# CSS property is not working for main body class

Tags: html, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

[This](http://www.orickstelecom.com/) is the website when we minimize the browser to 320px all of the respective classses css properties are working fine, except for the main body class. Its width is not change able even if i use important in the properties, How to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `min-width: 960px;` set in grid.css.  You'll need to override this too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `body { min-width: 960px;}` is set without a media query on line 2 of grid.css